# Eclipse plugin editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, eclipse-plugin

I want to create an editor in eclipse (as eclipse plug-in), for a java class that implement some interfaces i created. The editor will let the user edit some information (using a form) that will be put into the java class. - very much like in EJB editor.
I want java files that implement this interface to open the editor.

1. How can I replace the values in the class without the need to re-generate it (because the user might have edited some of the source code in the class)?
2. How can I link the editor to open just some java files?

Thank you.

Comment: when you say just some java files, do you mean a subset of java files? If so how do you identify the subset?

Comment: If you read the rest of the question: It's files that contain a class that implements some interface.

Answer (score 2):

Use the JDT to get access to the java class and change parts of its contents using the AST of the java class.

Maybe this [article](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

1) I suggest that you read Eclipse documentation in details as I don't think that it will be trivial.
2) I suppose that Eclipse has some mime-type associations API, so you'd just use that.